# RMagick can't read PDF file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am trying to resize a PDF file through RMagick. First, I am trying to read the file into the ImageList class

```
image_path = "#{Rails.root}/tmp/consignment_note.pdf"
image_list = ::Magick::ImageList.new(image_path)
```

The file exists at the specified location and I can access it through the ruby `File.open()`, but the image_list is empty after running above code. Any advice?

Comment: Did you install Ghostscript?

Comment: Thanks, installing ghostscript fixed the problem, but when I resize the document from A4 to A5, the resulting pdf is of very poor quality

Comment: You need to set the density before reading the image, I don't know how to do that in RMagick.